# Azure Kinect Green Screen building

Tags: azure, executable, building, azurekinect

I'm having a hard time building an executable from the example provided from https://github.com/microsoft/Azure-Kinect-Sensor-SDK/tree/develop/examples/green_screen

I've tried using cmake GUI, VS 2017's cmake but to no avail. I'm not even sure how I should be installing OpenCV. Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is very odd behaviour. I would suggest verifying that all the steps in the [Building and Dependencies](https://github.com/microsoft/Azure-Kinect-Sensor-SDK/blob/develop/docs/building.md) page are followed as described. As you can see is not just OpenCV. Please go through the list and verify you have all the required software.

~Pino

Comment: Yes, AMD64 stands for x64 and the like. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64